# Python Django Post Queue

Tags: python, django, queue, task

Hi I have a Django Project. In my project, I want to queue all incoming post requests and show the sequence number. First in, first out. How can I go about this? Because I have created a project where many people can submit requests at the same time. When I receive a request like this at the same time, the server may crash or delays may occur.For this, I thought about queuing and giving sequence numbers to users, but I couldn't find much source about it. For example, 10 requests came all of a sudden, the server calls the functions on the backend and the sequence number 10 appears. Then the user who made the first request gets a response and the sequence number drops to 9.

Answer (score 1):

```
queue = []
 
# Adding elements to the queue
queue.append('1')
queue.append('2')
queue.append('3')
 
print("Initial queue")
print(queue)
 
# Removing elements from the queue
print("\nElements dequeued from queue")
print(queue.pop(0))
print(queue.pop(0))
print(queue.pop(0))
 
print("\nQueue after removing elements")
print(queue)


And then just add a user ID section
```

Comment: This didn't solve my problem, I think I didn't explain what I wanted to say clearly. When the user posts a request in an html page, I want the program to queue these requests and show the sequence number while running the functions from the backend.These requests can sometimes be at the same time, when the server is not blocked, it needs to be queued and displayed. When the functions are finished, it needs to show the return value and decrease the order